# Drawing Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, machine-learning

Can someone help me to draw this pdf? I really don't have an idea how to convert a function to pdf. Thank you

p(x | c) = 1/3 for 1 <= x <= 4 and P(c) = 0.5

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $P(C_1\cap C_2)=0$?

Then $P(C_1)+P(C_2)=1$ and $\{C_1,C_2\}$ partitions the probability space.

You want to find $p(X)$ from the conditional probabilities.

$p(X)=P(C_1)p(X|C_1)+P(C_2)p(X|C_2)=\frac{1}{6}\mathbf{1}_{x \in [1,4]}(x)+ \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{1}_{x \in [2,3]}(x)$ This simplifies to:

$p(x)=\frac{1}{6}\mathbf{1}_{x \in \{[1,2)\cup (3,4]\}}(x)+\frac{2}{3}\mathbf{1}_{x \in [2,3]}(x)$

Its just a symmetric stepwise uniform density with tails at 1/6 and a center at 2/3.

BTW: This is called a [mixture distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). Where $P(C_1),P(C_2)$ are the mixture probabilities.

Comment: Actually this is a part of my homework question and it wants me to draw the corresponding pdf. What do you mean by mixed-distribution? The whole question is below.

p(x|C1) = 1/3    for 1 <= x <= 4
                 0      elsewhere

p(x|C2) = 1       for 2 <= x <= 3 
                 0      elsewhere

Assume P(C1)=P(C2)=0. 5.

Comment: @logic_apprentice I guess I misunderstood your notation. Are the P's densities or probabilities? It seems like you have too much probability. If they are densities, then you simply have a uniform distribution on [1,4] with a spike at c with height 0.5. This spike will contribute NO probability.

Comment: P(C1) and P(C2) are prior probabilities

Comment: @logic_apprentice revised